# Ignoring TypeScript "no inputs were found in config file"

Tags: typescript

I'm building a boilerplate/framework that allows someone to have but doesn't require them to use TypeScript files. This framework runs the TypeScript compiler in watch mode (`tsc --watch`) so that files that get dropped in the project directory get automatically built. A newly created project *will not have any TypeScript files* when starting out. Unfortunately, when running `tsc --watch`, I'm confronted with the annoying error:

> no inputs were found in config file

I get that this is useful for the majority of cases where people don't want TypeScript to just do nothing if the config file is misconfigured, but in my case I want TSC to enter watch mode and just do nothing if there are no TS files.

Is there a way to get `tsc` to not care when there are no TypeScript source files to compile?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.

Before, I was exclusively using an `include` and `exclude` option with file patterns. I found that by also adding an empty `"files": []` option, `tsc` leaves me alone about there being no TypeScript files. Hooray!